# filter email in php using preg

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-replace

Is there any email filter in php other than `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`? I want `.` and `@` to be compulsory in the user email.

Is there any built-in filter that can help me to accomplish this task?

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` does that. Can you specify what's exactly wrong with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`? Either way you can always write regexp.

Comment: @zogby its not written in their manual that it searches for . and @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php#101693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) does it.

Without `.` :

```
<?php 

$email = "user@emailcom";
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
    var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)); 
}else{ 
    var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));    
} 

// returns false
```

Without `@` :

```
<?php 

$email = "useremail.com";
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
    var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)); 
}else{ 
    var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));    
} 

// returns false too
```

With a correct mail :

```
<?php 

$email = "user@email.com";
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
    var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)); 
}else{ 
    var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));    
} 

// returns user@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You want, that email contains dot (.) in his name? Like my.email@gmail.com? Maybe this could help...

This return true (with dot in name):

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\.[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i', 'my.email@gmail.com')
```

This return false (without dot in name):

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\.[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i', 'myemail@gmail.com')
```

Comment: that regex definitely isn't right since it requires a `.` in the username portion of the address

Comment: he didn't write if dot must be in username or domain

Comment: Well requiring a dot in the first half immediately means that something like 99.5% of possible valid email addresses aren't recognised.

Answer (score 0):

FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL does NOT allow incomplete e-mail addresses to be validated. If you are using PHP >5.2, then this one is safe to use.